# Unwind segue crashes after ABPeoplePickerNavigationController use

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, abpeoplepickerview

I have a modally presented view (call it 'current view'). It has an unwind segue to the modally presented view before it. Current view has a button hooked up to the following code:

```
- (IBAction)inviteUser:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Current view is set as the delegate to the picker and implements the following delegate methods:

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
{
    // Do nothing
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return NO;
}
```

Nothing crazy so far. When I press the button, my contacts list comes up. I can select a contact and I'm sent back to current view with no crashes and no apparent changes.

Now, current view has another button (back button) hooked up to an unwind segue that I created in the storyboard. I did this by ctrl-dragging from the button to 'Exit' and picking the unwind function I had defined in previous view:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToThisList:(UIStoryboardSegue*)unwindSegue
{

}
```

Here's the clincher. If I press the back button while in current view, and I **haven't** gone into the address book while in this view, it unwinds correctly. No problems. I can go back and forth between those views all day. However, if I **have** gone into the address book and returned to current view, pressing the back button results in an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. It makes no difference if I leave the address book by picking a contact or pressing cancel.

I'm completely lost. Pls halp.

Comment: Also, the problem doesn't occur on the simulator.

Comment: Sometimes I get these errors in the debugger: "unrecognized selector ... [__NSCFString barStyle]" and "[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction". Other times, I can unwind once successfully, but not a second time.

Comment: The previous view does have a UINavigationBar, but it is not referenced programatically. There are buttons on it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a test xcode project, having two scenes in navigation, 
Pushed the current view (second scene), from first View.

Then implemented the inviteUser method in current view, and I unwinded segue to the first view, after dismissing ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, without an error. Please check there migh be some other error, I guess.

Comment: Mine aren't in navigation. They're all modal. But that's a solid idea. I'll try recreating my view flow in a barebones environment.

Comment: Mate, pushing a scene and unwinding it works only in navigation.

Comment: That's not true. You can unwind from a modal segue.